# 2002 WRX Impreza overheats despite cooling system overhaul

Tags: subaru, overheating, impreza, wrx

This is a 2002 Subaru Impreza WRX.

I just bought it from some lady and it's overheating badly. I took it to a mechanic and changed the radiator, got a radiator flush with the water hose, put in a new thermostat, they told me my head gasket was good that I didn't need to change it, and I also put in a new coolant temperature sensor.

If anybody knows what the problem could be please let me know because it's still overheating.

Comment: Have you checked the cooling fan is working? and it operates at the correct temperature?

Comment: Is it actually losing coolant can you see? If it's not leaking then in addition to MadMarky's suggestions I'd also consider changing the radiator cap - these can be problematic on this model and are a cheap and easy part to change as well.

Comment: Could you check the water pressure someway and see if it’s upto spec (if there is a spec for it)

Comment: Did the mechanic pressure test the system? Also you can test the cap as well. You could just be losing pressure and therefore losing circulation.

Answer (score 3):

The cooling fan and water pump are usual suspects that you did not mention yet. A bad water pump will overheat an engine really quickly because there is insufficient coolant flow, a broken cooling fan usually only becomes a problem when a car is stationary or in slow traffic.

Comment: Don't just check the water pump, have it replaced along with the timing kit all at the same time. You don't want to solve a cooling problem and immediately loose an entire engine to timing failure. @motosubatsu also has a good point about the rad caps.